# Functions are not valid as a React Child - When trying to destructure each icon inside a map

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of social media icons that I am mapping through to display each social media item. Each prop `socialPlatform` which is a string (Facebook, Instagram, LinkedIn) should have its own icon.

Doing it the ugly and not so clean way like checking if `socialPlatform` equals one of the platforms then return the correct icon. But this can get messy.

I am trying to do the following `icon[socialPlatform]` the `icon` is an object of values-based which equals each platform.

Doing this results in: `Functions are not valid as a React Child`

Am I doing something from?

```
 <div className="grid place-self-center lg:justify-end">
          <div className="flex col-span-2 space-x-3 text-white lg:col-span-5">
            {socials.length &&
              socials.map((item: any) => {
                const { _key, href, socialPlatform } = item;
                // let icon;

                const icon = {
                  facebook: () => (
                    <div>
                      <FacebookLogo />
                    </div>
                  ),
                  instagram: () => (
                    <div>
                      <InstagramLogo />
                    </div>
                  ),
                  linkedin: () => (
                    <div>
                      <LinkedinLogo />
                    </div>
                  ),
                };

                // socialPlatform === "linkedin" &&
                //   (icon = (
                //     <LinkedinLogo
                //       size={25}
                //       weight="duotone"
                //       color="#FF99F3"
                //     />
                //   ));

                // socialPlatform === "facebook" &&
                //   (icon = (
                //     <FacebookLogo
                //       size={25}
                //       weight="duotone"
                //       color="#FF99F3"
                //     />
                //   ));

                // socialPlatform === "instagram" &&
                //   (icon = (
                //     <InstagramLogo
                //       size={25}
                //       weight="duotone"
                //       color="#FF99F3"
                //     />
                //   ));

                return (
                  <a
                    key={_key}
                    href={href}
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noreferrer"
                  >
                    <span className="sr-only"> {socialPlatform} </span>

                    {icon[socialPlatform]}
                  </a>
                );
              })}
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning function component instead of React Nodes, change it to:

```
const icon = {
  facebook: (
    <div>
      <FacebookLogo />
    </div>
  ),
  // ...
}

return <>{icon[socialPlatform]}</>
```

Or, without change, you need to actual mount the components:

```
// If this is the case
const icon = {
  facebook: () => (
    <div>
      <FacebookLogo />
    </div>
  ),
  // ...
}

const IconComponent = icon[socialPlatform];

return <IconComponent/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your `icon` variable is an object of functions. You can execute them as [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
return (
  <a key={_key} href={href} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
    <span className="sr-only"> {socialPlatform} </span>
    {icon[socialPlatform]()}
  </a>
);
```

Comment: Dont to this, you actually remount the node on every render, call it with the actual API, see docs or check my answer.